# How can I enable multiple users to login using OTP on one mobile device using react-native

Tags: react-native

Example of UseCase: I am a teacher, with this mobile device. I need to create and enable 40 students to use the app, from their userIDs which are authenticated using my mobile number, as they do not have their mobile device with them in class. They might go back home and sign in from their devices, but they might also sign in from the teacher's device. They don't want to use a password. They prefer an OTP. How can we do this?

Context:
We work with youth in the community, and need to enable many of them to sign in to an app using OTP, using the same mobile device. How can we maintain the integrity of the user's digital identity while making login easy?

The react-native app allows users to create UserIds using OTP or Facebook or Google OAuth. While we can only sign in one user per mobile device, we have the requirement to get multiple youth to sign in using one device. They need not stay signed on. OTP seems to need a single mobile number, and not multiple unique user Ids to be created with one mobile number

How can we design the backend and code such that this need can be met?

Comment: First of all, the question is too broad. To infer your question, are you saying that user should be able to log in using OTP and that other users should be able to log in to the registered mobile phone if they know the OTP number?

Comment: @hongdevelop thank you for answering. Example of UseCase: I am a teacher, with this mobile device. I need to create and enable 40 students to use the app, from their userIDs which are authenticated using my mobile number, as they do not have their mobile device with them in class. They might go back home and sign in from their devices, but they might also sign in from the teacher's device. They don't want to use a password. They prefer an OTP.

Comment: use usernames and otp's.

Comment: @JuniusL. can you please elaborate?